# multiprocessing not updating dataframe as the process defines

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run the following process using the multiprocessing library (there's only one process because I'm still testing it, the idea would be to run the process for several datasets. That's why I'm using multiprocessing).

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
start = time.perf_counter()

processes = []

p = Process(target=test, args=[df_1])
p.start()
processes.append(p)

for process in processes:
    process.join()

finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} s')
```

where the test function is:

```
def test(df):
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        results = similarity(embeddings, df_acordaos,i,0)
        df.at[i,'SIMILARITY_ALL']=similarity_formated(results)
    print(df_1.columns)
    return df
```

The 'print()' performed inside the function displays the created column 'SIMILARITY_ALL' however, when printing the columns outside the function, the created column 'SIMILARITY_ALL' does not appear.

print of the dataset columns inside the function: [image]

print of the dataset columns outside the function: [image]

Comment: Because your function is working with `df` and you have printed `df_1`.  They are not the same.

Comment: This is not how Python multiprocessing works. Starting a new process creates a whole new Python process with its own memory space (and a new namespace) that is seperate from the parents one. You have to deliberatly transport object from one to another to get what you want (which is using the pickle protocol). Look into `multiprocessing.Pool`, and maybe use `.apply_async`, to achieve your goal.

Comment: Got it, I tried to use the `.apply_async` but it´s seems like it can not be used to return a dataframe. Is there anyway to save this column in parallel?

Comment: That's doesn't sound correct. Try `p = mp.Pool(); res = p.apply_async(test, [df]); df = res.get(); print(df)`. (The `print(df_1.columns)` in `test` doesn't really make sense.)